# Update UITableView data when returning from detailView

Tags: objective-c, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I update the UITableView's data source when viewDidAppear method is called on the ViewController that holds the tableview. So every time the user returns from the detailView the data is updated.

So the issue is that the UI is interrupted and the cell is selected until it is finished.

Is NSOperationQueue the best way to correct this?

Thanks for some suggestions.

Comment: What about updating the data source in viewWillAppear: instead?

Comment: @ageektrapped, when the view is loaded first time the information used to updating the data source is requested in viewDidLoad. So putting the update call there gives me NSInvalidArgumentException. I do the update based on another response.

Comment: OK, if I do the initial request in **- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated** and the update data source in **- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated** the UI don´t get stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would do these kind of things using either blocks or an NSOperation.  The important thing is that the UI doesn't get blocked at any time if you can help it.